# Remove all event listeners attached to a key using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I want to remove all event listeners currently attached to a key board key using javascript. I know It's possible for HTML elements by cloning and replacing that particular element but how to do it for a key?
For example pressing `Q` in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com) opens the dropdown so how can I prevent it?
Things I tried but didn't work:

```
onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.key == 'q'){
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    e.stopPropagation()
  }
}

onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.key == 'q'){
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    e.stopPropagation()
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't attach events to the keys of the keyboard, events are always attached to the DOM elements (or to `document` or `window`). Please show how you've originally added the "events to keys". Or if you're programming an extension, then we need to know how the target page has attached the events.

Comment: i debugged and it's a keyup event attached to document

Comment: and `document.onkeyup=null` didn't work

Comment: Then you've to try to remove the listener. If it's an anonymous function, there's not much you can do, since listeners attached with `addEventListener` can't be removed without a reference to the actual function. Also, `onxxx` listeners are properties of the elements, those are not connected with the listeners added with `addEventListener` (or with inline listeners, if that matters). If you can't get a reference to the function, then you're out of luck, as it's probably not practical, or even possible to rebuild the entire document without the said listener.

Comment: I got it removed by setting `useCapture` flag in `addEventListener()`

Comment: @GorvGoyl please consider writing your code up as an answer.  I know it's a very very old question, but I'm trying to basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround by executing event handler in the capturing phase i.e. setting `useCapture` to true.

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if(e.key == 'q'){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  }
}, true); //useCapture
```

Please do post if there are any better solutions.

Comment: Thank god, this really helps! THANK YOU!